# checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method events not wroking

Tags: magento-1.9

```
     <events>
    <checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
        <observers>
            <Training_Customcheckout_sales_order_shipment_save_before>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Training_Customcheckout_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>setShippingCommentToQuote</method>
            </Training_Customcheckout_sales_order_shipment_save_before>
        </observers>
    </checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
    <checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
        <observers>
            <Training_Customcheckout_sales_order_shipment_save_after1>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Training_Customcheckout_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>setShippingCommentToOrder</method>
            </Training_Customcheckout_sales_order_shipment_save_after1>
        </observers>
    </checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
</events>
```

I have call this events and in observer:

```
class Projectwork_Deliverydate_Model_Observer extends Varien_Object{
    public function setShippingCommentToQuote($observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $quote = $event->getQuote();
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $orderComment = $request->getPost('shippingComment', false);
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $session->setData('shipping_comment', $orderComment);
    }

    public function setShippingCommentToOrder($observer)
    {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $shippingComment = $session->getData('shipping_comment');

        if($shippingComment){
            $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->setShippingComment($shippingComment);
        }
    }


}
```

But its not working when I click continue to payment method from front end.

Comment: Please, share your code and what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

In your event configuration, you have specified the observer class as `Training_Customcheckout_Model_Observer` and however you have defined your observer in the class `Projectwork_Deliverydate_Model_Observer`.

I think this is a copy-paste issue. If your working module is `Projectwork_Deliverydate` then change the `class` attribute to `Projectwork_Deliverydate_Model_Observer`.

**Note:** However the best practice is specifying the `class` attribute like `namespace_module/observer`. Which will be converted to `Namespace_Module_Model_Observer` by Magento. This will give us the flexibility to extend or rewrite the observer class.

So in your case, it should be: `projectwork_deliverydate/observer`. You also need to define model class definition inside `global` node in order to make it work.